# Does an Indian with UK residence require a visa to visit the Netherlands?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, netherlands, uk-residents

My partner has an Indian passport with a permanent residence card in the UK.

Does he need a visa to travel to the Netherlands?

Comment: What is your nationality? Are you married?

Comment: my nationality is Dutch and we are legally married. he had for 5 years an residence card of a family member of an EEA national.

Comment: He is traveling on his own, and this permanent residence card is issued last year in Liverpool by the UK border agency (immigration department).

Comment: He will need a visa in that case.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not joining or accompanying your partner, then they have no access to the freedom of movement provisions.

A UK permanent residence visa (I assume you mean ILR) is not recognized as a valid instrument for Schengen because the UK does not provide reciprocity.

So yes, your partner will need a Schengen visa.